# Saving video file to documents directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, file

I have some code that exports a video file to the camera roll. How can I save the same file to the documents directory as well?

**Code**

```
self.exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
self.exportSession.outputURL = url;
self.exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
self.exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
self.exportSession.videoComposition = videoComposition;

self.exportProgressBarTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.1 target:self.delegate selector:@selector(updateProgress) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

__block id weakSelf = self;

[self.exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{            NSLog (@"i is in your block, exportin. status is %ld",(long)self.exportSession.status);
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [weakSelf exportDidFinish:self.exportSession withCompletionBlock:completion];
            });
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Modify your `exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler` with following**

```
// it checks different completion states and at the end it stores to `Camera role`

[exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
    BOOL success = false;
    switch ([exporter status]) {
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
            success = true;
            NSLog(@"Export Completed");
            break;
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusWaiting:
            NSLog(@"Export Waiting");
            break;
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusExporting:
            NSLog(@"Export Exporting");
            break;
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
        {
            NSError *error = [exporter error];
            NSLog(@"Export failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

            break;
        }
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Export canceled");

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (success == true) {

        ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        [assetLibrary writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:url completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
            NSError *removeError = nil;
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:url error:&removeError];
        }];

    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)save_photo_video_document:(NSURL *)Asset_url :(NSString *)Document_path 
{
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
    self.navigationController.view.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
    spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    [spinner setFrame:CGRectMake(120, 200, 80, 80)];
    [spinner.layer setCornerRadius:10.0 ];
    [spinner setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [spinner startAnimating];
    [self.view addSubview:spinner];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
    {
        ALAssetRepresentation * rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
        long  long  bufferSize=1024*1024;
        FILE* f = fopen([Document_path cStringUsingEncoding:1], "wb+");
        if (f == NULL) {
            return;
        }
        Byte * buffer = (Byte*)malloc(bufferSize);
        int read = 0, offset = 0, written = 0;
        NSError* err;
        if (buffer != 0) {
            do {
                read = [rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:offset length:bufferSize error:&err];
                written = fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), read, f);
                offset += read;
            } while (read != 0);
        }
        fclose(f);
        free(buffer);
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.view.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
            [spinner stopAnimating];
        });
    };
    ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *myerror)
    {
    };
    if(Asset_url)
    {
        ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        [assetslibrary assetForURL:Asset_url resultBlock:resultblock failureBlock:failureblock];
    }
    });
}
```